How to save a World background image .png to file
I am learning Blender and have brought a spaceship model from cgtrader.com.  It has a star field background that uses "hdr.png".  I want to save hdr.png to file.  There seems to be no Blender menu option to do this.  So could I do it with python? This post shows how to use python to load an image file as background but I want to save the background to a image file. blender.stackexchange.com: Camera - set background image - python


Hello, if you want to pack the image (?), go into File > External Data > Pack Resources, or open the image in the Image Editor and Image > Pack

Ah the image editor with its drop down list can display and save all the images in the .blend file.  Thank you

To pack all the images go into File > External Data > Pack Resources, to pack one image open the image in the Image Editor and Image > Pack.
